# Getting an error in Redux: "Encountered two children with the same key". How to resolve this error?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm learning Redux. In the same container, I would like to use mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps. If I separate these into different containers, I can get this to work without errors, but if I try to put them both in the same container, for some reason it gives the following error:

```
"bundle.js:2296 Warning: flattenChildren(...): 
Encountered two children with the same key, `.$1`. 
Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, 
only the first child will be used."
```

Is it ok to use mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps simultaneously in the same container? Everything works, but I still get the error on the console, and would like to figure out what it means exactly.

Here is my container. (I have to actions: fetchAstronaut and showNotification):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { fetchAstronaut } from '../actions/index';
import { showNotification } from '../actions/index';

class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: ''
        }
    }
    displaySearch(e) {
        this.setState({ text: e.target.value })
    }

    formSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.fetchAstronaut(this.state.text);
        this.setState({ text: ''});
        this.props.showNotification();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <form onSubmit={(e) => this.formSubmit(e)}>
                        <input
                            value = { this.state.text }
                            onChange={(e) => this.displaySearch(e) }
                        />
                        <button type="submit">Search</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h1>{this.props.notification}</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ notification }) {
    return { notification };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators( { fetchAstronaut, showNotification }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely ok to use mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps simultaneously in the same container, and error you are seeing is lies elsewhere.

Whenever you are passing react list of components, you shoud assign each of those components unique id. For instance if you have code:

```
const Comp = (props) => {
 const l =[1,2,3,4]
 const lc = l.map((ix) => (<p>{ix}</p>))
 return (
  <div>{lc}</div>
 )
}
```

would give you error similar to yours. To fix it you should change it to:

```
const lc = l.map((ix) => (<p key={ix}>{ix}</p>))
```

so that each paragraph gets its its unique key.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's ok to use *mapStateToProps* and *mapDispatchToProps*, in fact it's really recommendable.

As for the warning, it's a react-JSX warning: you're including 2 divs at the same level without a key. They must have a 'key' parameter and they must be different.

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div key='1'>
                <form onSubmit={(e) => this.formSubmit(e)}>
                    <input
                        value = { this.state.text }
                        onChange={(e) => this.displaySearch(e) }
                    />
                    <button type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div key='2'>
                <h1>{this.props.notification}</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```